# javax validation constraints not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, constraints

I cannot get annotations such as @NotEmpty, @NotBlank and @NotNull to fire in my Spring Boot application.

I've followed this (maven) example:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

...and I don't see what I am doing wrong.

POJO:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class College
{    
    @NotBlank
    private String collegeCode;
.
.
.
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCollege", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String addCollege(@Valid @ModelAttribute("college") College college, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpSession session)
{
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) //this is never true
    {
        logger.debug("Errors when adding new college!!!");
        return "admin/colleges/addCollege";
    }
    collegeProcessor.saveCollege(college);
    return getAllColleges(model, session);
}
```

Screen:

```
<form action="#" th:action="${addOrEdit} == 'add' ? @{/addCollege} : @{/updateCollege}" th:object="${college}" method="post">

    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>College Code</td>
            <td><input size="10" name="collegeCode" th:field="*{collegeCode}"/></td>
            <div id="errors" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('collegeCode')}" th:errors="*{collegeCode}"></div>
        </tr>
.
.
.
```

As well as @NotBlank, I have tried @NotEmpty and @NotNull, but the same thing happens.  My screen does not validate the input, and allows a college object with an empty collegeCode to be saved.

The interesting thing is if I change my POJO to use the deprecated Hibernate validator instead...

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class College
{
    @NotBlank
    private String collegeCode;
.
.
.
```

...then the validation DOES fire, and the screen prevents me from saving a College object with an empty collegeCode.

Can anyone tell me why my validation doesn't work when using the javax.validation.constraints validators?

Comment: Additional information: I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.5, and for the persistence layer I have MyBatis, NOT hibernate.

Answer (score 38):

Since version 2.3.0.RELEASE the validation starter is not included in web/webflux starters by default, you need to add it manually. More details [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

Include Maven dependency for 2.3.0.RELEASE in pom.xml, however, it is not required for lower version of Spring Boot Application.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I've figured out this problem. I had the same problem and tried to lower spring boot version. I lowered my spring boot version from 2.3.0.RELEASE to 2.2.7.RELEASE and it works)
Maybe this answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a bean MethodValidationPostProcessor  to your context

```
 @Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 0):

having exactly the same issue, no idea what to do. All needed classes are in the classpath, no jar hells etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
I m using spring boot 2.3.12 the contract first api is generate with swagger 3.0.0:
```

that's an attribute generated:

```
 @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
  @NotNull
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }
```

here are the dependencies i used :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 

    <!-- Validation API support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi a would like to get the error, I simple get no inserted row